# Exception Propagation/Handling with Try/Catch in different Asp.NET/IIS Versions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, dropzone.js

**Background info:**

In my asp.net (.NET target framework is 4.6.1) application I am using dropzone.js client-side to upload files. The server-side code that handles the upload is surrounded in a try/catch. When an exception is thrown, the error should be caught, logged, the response status code set to `500`, `"An error occurred"` should be written to the response and finally a call to `Response.End()`.

I have two different environments that I am running this application in. The first is my development environment (Windows 10 Pro with application running on local instance of IIS 10). The second is my UAT environment (Azure VM with Windows Server 2012 R2 with application running on IIS 8.5).

**Problem:**

When an exception occurs (inside of the try/catch), the response received by my browser is different between Dev and UAT.

*In Dev*, the response is plain text `An error occurred`.

[image: dev error]

*In UAT*, the response looks like the raw HTML from the IIS error page (and this is captured by dropzone and displayed horribly in the error bubble).

[image: uat error]

**Code**

My front end code for dropzone.js (for the sake of completeness, I don't believe the issue is here):

```
$("#attachDZ").dropzone({
    url: "/file/upload.aspx",
    maxFilesize: 1024,
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files here or click to upload."
});
```

This is the back end code (in the `Page_Load` for `upload.aspx.cs`) :

```
try
{
    // Get the data
    foreach (string pf in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFile postedfile = (HttpPostedFile)Request.Files[pf];
        string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(postedfile.FileName);

        Byte[] UploadBytes = new Byte[postedfile.ContentLength];
        postedfile.InputStream.Read(UploadBytes, 0, postedfile.ContentLength);

        tTempAtt file = tTempAtt.NewInstance();
        file.ContentType = postedfile.ContentType;
        file.File = UploadBytes;
        file.FileName = strFileName;
        file.Insert();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogProxy.WriteError(ex);
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    Response.Write("An error occurred");
}
finally
{
    Response.End();
}
```

In the web.config for both Dev and UAT I have `<customErrors mode="Off"/>`. I am totally stumped as to what the difference is between these two environments that would cause the response to be different even when the exception thrown is the same.

It appears that, in UAT, the `catch` is being ignored (which shouldn't be possible, right?). I've removed the `try`/`catch` in my Dev environment and forced an exception and was able to reproduce the same results as I found in UAT. I have not been able to reproduce the issue in my Dev environment without removing the `try`/`catch`...even if I build in release mode and set the debug flag in the web.config to `false`.

Does anyone have any ideas? I attempted to include the most relevant information, but please let me know if there were other things I missed. Any help would be much appreciated.